# Is it possible to take a screenshot of all the visible items displayed on the monitor of a client machine from a sever?

Tags: php

Is it possible to take a screenshot of all the visible items displayed on the monitor of a client machine from a sever?

Comment: through PHP? I'm gonna venture: No.

Comment: What a security nightmare that would be.

Answer (score 4):

No. You would need some kind of client-side technology for this, but I doubt it is possible due to the restrictions in which browsers plugin operate.
For example, Fogbugz, a bug tracking software, has an option to do screen grabs, but to use it you need to install a local program on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

from the client should send the items displayed for example with AJAX, and in server related to the capture of the user session

Answer (score 0):

... a Java applet or an Activex control might able to pull it off. In theory anyway, in Java's case through JNI, so me thinks. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible it is definitely not with PHP. PHP is a server-side language, all of its work is done once the page is returned from the server.